# Invalid content when nCurses app comes from background

Tags: c++, posix, ncurses

I have observed odd behavior with my nCurses app when putting it to background/foreground. After a couple of times my window shows invalid content. I suspect that when sending `SIGSTOP`/`SIGCONT` signals to my app I need to be handle those and refresh window, but I can't find any note about it. Does nCurses has some way of refreshing window when coming back from background? Or the reason can be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ncurses does have a [handler](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/ncurses/tty/lib_tstp.c#L137) for [`SIGTSTP`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Signal-Handlers), which it sets up in `initscr` — if it is in the [default state](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/ncurses/tty/lib_tstp.c#L368):

> **`SIGTSTP`**
>   This  handles the stop signal, used in job control.  When resuming
>   the process,  this  implementation  discards  pending  input  with
>   flushinput  (see  [curs_util(3x)](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html)), and repaints the screen assuming
>   that it has been completely altered.  It also  updates  the  saved
>   terminal modes with def_shell_mode (see [curs_kernel(3x)](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html))

Comment: Thanks for previous answer, I have followup question. In my app I'm scanning keyboard characters in loop, so when my app goes background and back to foreground I'm experiencing getting some junk character. I would like to call flushinp() when process comes fg but default nurses SIGCONT handler is not doing that. How I can piggyback flushinp() in this case?